# Bad wkhtmltopdf's path: bundler: command not found: which

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, pdf, wkhtmltopdf

I'm using the wkhtmltopdf gem in Rails on Windows but it does not work. I get this error:
"Bad wkhtmltopdf's path: bundler: command not found: which".
It works with exe but i don't want use exe_path, i just want to use the gem.
This is my wkhtmltopdf config file:

```
# WickedPDF Global Configuration
#
# Use this to set up shared configuration options for your entire application.
# Any of the configuration options shown here can also be applied to single
# models by passing arguments to the `render :pdf` call.
#
# To learn more, check out the README:
#
# https://github.com/mileszs/wicked_pdf/blob/master/README.md

WickedPdf.config = {
  # Path to the wkhtmltopdf executable: This usually isn't needed if using
  # one of the wkhtmltopdf-binary family of gems.
  # exe_path: 'C:\Program Files\wkhtmltopdf\bin\wkhtmltopdf.exe'
  
}
```

I'm also using the gem 'wicked_pdf' gem 'wkhtmltopdf-binary'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the wkhtmltopdf gem does not support the Windows operating system. I found this in the source code:

```
suffix = case RbConfig::CONFIG['host_os']
when /linux/
  (RbConfig::CONFIG['host_cpu'] == 'x86_64') ? 'linux_amd64' : 'linux_x86'
when /darwin/
  'darwin_x86'
else
  raise "Invalid platform. Must be running on linux or intel-based Mac OS."
end
```

The other hint is the fact you received: `command not found: which`. `which` is a Unix command to identify the location of executables, not available for Windows. Sorry

Comment: got it. Thank you @arpie!

Answer (score 0):

this worked for me

```
exe_path: 'C://Program Files/wkhtmltopdf/bin/wkhtmltopdf.exe'
```

Comment: how about suggesting a more generic answer, than a path on your PC?